# Chrome extension is not sending the data from the popup to my node.js/express server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome-extension

The extension is meant to be just a log in, so it sends the data from the log in to a server using node.js/express . I think the problem is im assuming that the popup works as an html page and some permission on chrome like 'CORS'. Here is some of the code:

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "CTRL",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Aplicacion para el control de contenido en google Chrome",
    "icons": {
        "16": "imagenes/Logo.png",
        "48": "imagenes/Logo.png",
        "128": "imagenes/Logo.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon":"imagenes/Logo.png",
        "default title": "CTRL",
        "default_popup": "archivo/popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false    
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs","documents"]  
}
```

Popup.html:

```html
        User: <input type="text" id="User" placeholder="User"><br>
        Password: <input type="text"  placeholder="Password" id="Password" ><br>
        <button type="submit"  id='boton'>ENVIAR</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Server:

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require("path");

let app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/archivo')));

app.post('/CTRL', function(req, res) {
    let usuario = req.body;
    console.log('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
    res.send('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
});

app.listen('8000', function() {
    console.log('server corriendo puerto 8000');
  })
```

Client:

```
let nombre = document.getElementById('User');
let contrasena = document.getElementById('Password');
let boton = document.getElementById('boton');

boton.addEventListener('click', sendData);

function sendData(){

    let nombreSTR = nombre.value
    let contrasenaSTR = contrasena.value

    let usuario = {
        name: nombreSTR,
        passw: contrasenaSTR
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/CTRL', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(usuario),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Add localhost to permissions, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just add a permit to the fetch like this:

fetch('http://localhost:8000/CTRL', {
  mode:'no-cors',
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(usuario),
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }